# Writing code to import Google Font API into MailChimp?

Tags: css, mailchimp, google-font-api

I'm trying to insert this API code into MailChimp: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">`

I want the text to be light 300 but am totally lost. Can anyone help me code this?

```css
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="color:#000000"><strong>Ethiopia: </strong><br />
Prime Minister resigns abruptly after years of violent anti-government protests and a failed nationwide state of emergency. The country&rsquo;s future is uncertain.&nbsp;</span></span></span><br />
&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:14px"> <span style="color:#000000">John Smith, 35, Kosovo</span></span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the `<link rel=stylesheet..>` correctly in your HEAD section. Change the `font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif` to `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;` and add `font-weight: 300;`

```
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;"><span style="font-sizee:18px"><span style="color:#000000"><strong>Ethiopia: </strong><br />
Prime Minister resigns abruptly after years of violent anti-government protests and a failed nationwide state of emergency. The country&rsquo;s future is uncertain.&nbsp;</span></span></span><br />
&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;"><span style="font-size:14px"> <span style="color:#000000">John Smith, 35, Kosovo</span></span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the three steps as follows,

- Add the `<Link>` tag. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">`
- Change the current font family as follows: `font-family: 'Open Sans';`
- You want the text to be in 300px,then add `font-weight: 300;`

I've tried your example in jsFiddle and attached the corresponding link below.
https://jsfiddle.net/2ker4mop/2/